# how can I verify a specific Javascript object will be garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Is there any kind of assertion that I can make to verify that a particular object can be GC'ed in Javascript?  The purpose is to have a unit test that asserts a memory leak is fixed.

at this point I don't know of any direct language support for this - I don't think Javascript has weak references or finalizers, which is how I probably would have done this in Java or C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have any javascript code that detects if a specific object can be GCed.  The very code that would test it would keep it from being garbage collected because that code would, by definition, have a reference to it and the garbage collector will not GC something that still has a live reference to it.

The things you can do to verify that there is no memory leak:

1. Devise a test that runs the offending code over and over and measure the total memory usage of the browser to verify that the memory usage it not going up and up and up.
2. Assign a gigantic property value to the object (e.g. a mongo string) that is so large that you can clearly see if these objects are leaking in total memory usage.
3. Use various developer tools (which vary by browser) to look at the browser memory usage in finer detail.

Comment: ["A `FinalizationRegistry` object lets you request a callback when an object is garbage-collected."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry)

Comment: ["A `WeakRef` object lets you hold a weak reference to another object, without preventing that object from getting garbage-collected."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef)

Comment: @КонстантинВан - Yeah, this question/answer was from 2014, long before WeakRef existed.  But, even so, it's not clear the weakRef solves the question being asked here because the OP wants to know if a given object is eligible for GC or not.  The FinalizationRegistry make let you find out when it is GCed, but doens't tell you if it's it's eligible for GC before it gets GCed.  Anyway, this is such an old question, I don't think we need to spend more time on it.

Comment: Indeed, we can’t know it. The previous comments were about the line “_The very code that would test it would keep it from being garbage collected…_.”